# GitHub add content of new scripts to the old scripts

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I am new to the Git world-using the "lame" Git Hub Desktop version.

What I am trying to do is to "merge" new scripts with the current old scripts in a way so that the code
in the current old scripts will be unchanged BUT if there are new lines of code not existing in the current old scripts than those lines will be added...

And...  I have no idea on how to do that :)

I tried to do this with merging two branches but the behaviour is not the intended one (scripts get overwritten with the newer scripts).

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you really want to go through a real merge. I think you should go to the branch/revision of the old scripts and compare with the branch of the new scripts and pick the pieces you actually want to bring over to the old scripts. Any decent IDE will let you do it without much hassle.

Answer (score 0):

If you're the only one using that git repo - the file on the server after pushing local changes will always be the same as the one you have locally.

So if you first have a file like

```
foo() => print("bar);
```

And then want to add another line, you make the file

```
foo() => print("bar");
baz() => print("I'm the new function");
```

Then commit and push, and the file on the server will have both lines.

If you delete things from your local file and commit and push, those things will be deleted from the server's file too.